# Update my database without overwriting the previous records and showing them in a table

Tags: php, mysqli, html-table

i have an sql table that already has an initial value upon registration.
but the issue is how will i update the database without deleting the previous records of the the user in question.

```
consignmentno| location      | time | date 
1234567      | AGONA NKWANTA |1:15PM| 28-05-2017
```

i.e, i want them to be able to see the previous update and the new update in a table, please how will i achieve this aim.

```
consignmentno|           location   |       time    |      date             
1234567      | AGONA NKWANTA,Canada |1:15PM, 11:45am| 28-05-2017, 31-05-2017
```

and please will need the it to be able to show in the table as each rows.
i want my html table to look like this [image]

Comment: You will probably have to write some code... This isn't a free coding service, we help when you are stuck on a piece of code, we don't fully write things for you..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserv all old information, then, you need to use a INSERT query instead of a UPDATE one.

You need two tables: A first one with data who you need to not duplicate (For example, userID, passowrd), and a second table with duplicated data, example, Location.

Then, when you get the data on PHP, you can get it with a JOIN or a separate query, to obtain all locations recorded for the user.

The second query can give you the exact table you need without any transform of the data.

Comment: please can you give a more clearer explanation to this

Comment: Can you post your code and database model to give you any advice?

Comment: Will you edit your post to show database model / source code?